# Rails, SQL Injection, and Params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, security, sql-injection

I have this line of code inside of my controller.

```
user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
```

Should I have to worry about SQL injection with this line of code? Most of the examples I've seen for sql injection involve conditionals. I would assume this is a yes but want some outside input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only have to worry about this in SQL fragment methods like `where()`, `connection.execute()` or `find_by_sql()`, although if you want to be sure you can use a method like `sanitize_sql()`. I would recommend reading through [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#injection), most notably section 8 for your case.

Update:
For example

```
User.find_by_email("'' OR 1--")
```

would evaluate to

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["email", "'' OR 1--"]]
```

which would be sanitized.

Comment: I actually read through the guide before but felt like there was not enough info on when you should use escaping parameters.

Comment: You should not have to use them on any .find or find_by_x method because the counter measures that Rails institutes (escaping ’ , " , NULL character and line breaks) are automatically applied. The only instance where you need, and should, apply them are in fragment statements like the ones above. That being said, it would not hurt to be more careful but you should be safe with what you have. Hope this helps!

Comment: If you're using `where`, just make sure that you use the parameter binding features, and you'll be good there, too.  For example: `where(email: params[:email])` or `where("email = ?", params[:email])`.  See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection, section 8.2.4.